# Shader not drawing black with no light?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to implement specular reflection using values sampled from a grayscale, 1D texture as the multiplicative term.

I've implemented a toggle so I can see the difference between the two, but for some reason when the sampled color is enabled, the areas of the scene with no light display as a light gray, where without the sampling those same areas display as black.

Why is this? Here's the area where I'm setting the fragment color.

```
if(u_specularRamp == 1)
{
    specularAmount = clamp(specularAmount, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec2 texCoords = vec2(specularAmount, 0.5);
    vec4 sampledColor = texture(u_ramp_tex, texCoords);
    specularReflection = vec3(0.3 * sampledColor.x);
}
else
{
    specularReflection = vec3(0.3 * specularAmount);
}

FragColor = vec4(specularReflection, 1.0);
```

u_specularRamp is an integer uniform I'm passing in to toggle the sampled color on and off.

Comment: `FragColor = vec4(specularReflection, 1.0);` - is that intetional to write **only** the specular colour as an output?

Comment: Obviously this depends on the texture you sample. And apparently the texture is not black at the left edge.

Comment: @Matso Yes, this was so I could more easily see what was going on. This should output black where there is no specular highlight, and it does, except for when I'm sampling from a texture.

Comment: @NicoSchertler The texture is black at the left edge, but even if it wasn't, the areas that aren't being affected by the light should be output as solid black, and they are when I'm not sampling from a texture. Since I'm just outputting the specular, those areas should be outputting as solid black, but they aren't.

Comment: Then show how you calculate `u_specularRamp` and `specularAmount`. And it would help to show the texture, too.

Comment: @JacksonRushing Could You post it as an answer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue, in case anyone runs into this problem, this behaviour was caused by the texture parameter being set to GL_REPEAT. If you want black where there isn't any light, set that parameter to GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE